# Swift debugger - context variable override

Tags: ios, swift

I have this Swift code:

```
context = "this is the context"
print(context)
```

It prints out to console:

> this is the context

Now if I put a break-put exactly after that code above and issue this command:

```
(lldb) po context
"context"
```

What is this mysterious context and why is the Swift console showing "context"?

There must be a namespace conflict of some sort. How do I `po` my program's context and NOT whatever the other context is? What is that weird context?

Comment: just tried and didn't happen to me... might be a matter of which scope you are in

Comment: yes you are correct! Turns out that in addition to a variable named context I also had a struct with a static variable of the same name. The debugger would print out the ladder. That is werid